# Conditions on python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below.

```
{'key1': {'match': '45.56', 'key12': '45.56'},
 'key2': {'key21': '45.56', 'match2': '45.56'},
 'key3': {'key31': '45.56', 'key32': '45.56'}}
```

I want to grab key names where the value of the key is either match or match2.
My output should return

```
key1
key2
```

I tried the below code but it doesn't return anything:

```
    d = {'key1': {'match': '45.56', 'key12': '45.56'},
     'key2': {'key21': '45.56', 'match2': '45.56'},
     'key3': {'key31': '45.56', 'key32': '45.56'}}

for item in d:
    for row in item:
        if (row == 'match') | (row == 'match2'):
            print(item)
```

UPDATED QUESTION:

```
d = {'key1': {'match': '45.56', 'key12': '45.56'},
 'key2': {'key21': '45.56', 'match2': '45.56'},
 'key3': {'key31': '45.56', 'key32': '45.56'},
  'key4': ["key4", "key5"]}
```

I have update a question little bit, now I want my output to be like below. So basically the value of my last key is the list now. I want to apply the same logic and output of the match should be under match headings and unmatch ones under not match heading

```
match
key1
key2

not match
key3
key4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `any()` and membership check on set:

```
d = {'key1': {'match': '45.56', 'key12': '45.56'},
 'key2': {'key21': '45.56', 'match2': '45.56'},
 'key3': {'key31': '45.56', 'key32': '45.56'}}

to_look = {'match', 'match2'}

print([k for k, v in d.items() if any(x in to_look for x in v)])
# ['key1', 'key2']
```

Comment: I have updated a question little bit, now I want my output to be like below. So basically the value of my last key is the list now. I want to apply the same logic and output of the match should be under match headings and unmatch ones under not match heading

match
key1
key2

not match
key3
key4

Comment: You should ask a new question for this @Shanoo  .Otherwise the already posted correct answers are currently wrong when *they have correctly answered your original post*

Comment: The current output is matched output. For not matched output, you can do like: `set(d).difference(match)`. Obviously I'm not going to add to my answer, because other answers may seem wrong/the original question is *already answered* as @yatu says.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
d = {'key1': {'match': '45.56', 'key12': '45.56'},
  'key2': {'key21': '45.56', 'match2': '45.56'},
  'key3': {'key31': '45.56', 'key32': '45.56'}}
print(*[k for k in d if 'match' in d[k] or 'match2' in d[k]], sep='\n')
# or
print(*[k for k in d if any(['match' in d[k], 'match2' in d[k]])], sep='\n')
```

**Output** :

```
"key1"
"key2"
```